# How to identify a BytesIO object as a zip file (and not an Excel-File) with Python?

Tags: python, zip

I have to deal with `BytesIO` objects. Some of them are "regular" files but some of them are compressed via `ZipFile`. I need to identify that.

I was looking into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format) but did not understand all details.

One solution could be to check the first 4 bytes of the object

```
>>> f.getvalue()[:4]
b'PK\x03\x04'
```

But I am not sure if this is `True` for all kind of zip file formats.

**EDIT**: After discussion in the comments the question must be made more precise. I want to know if it is a zip file but not an Excel-File (which are zip files at all).

Comment: Yes, checking the header should be good enough: `f.getvalue()[:4] == b'PK\x03\x04'`. You can also call [zipfile.is_zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.is_zipfile), which does a more thorough check. Alternatively you can can try to read one of the files with [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile), and if any exceptions are raised it isn't a zip file.

Comment: Sidenode: This check doesn't work for Excel files (`.xlsx`) because they are also zip-like files. Damn. :D

Comment: Yeah, they're also zip files. What do you mean it doesn't work though? You want to test to see if it is a zip file, but not an .xlsx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to check if it is a zip file, but not an ooxml file:

```py
for buffer in buffers:
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(buffer):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer) as zip_file:
            try:
                # All ooxml documents contain this file
                zip_file.getinfo(name="[Content_Types].xml")
            except KeyError:
                # It is not an ooxml filelp
                pass
            else:
                # It is an ooxml file
                continue
            
            # Do stuff with the zip file that isn't an ooxml file
            print(zip_file.filename)
```